# How to stop both echos appearing (php)

Tags: php

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    if ($teacherusername == $dbTeacherUsername && $teacherpassword == $dbTeacherPassword) {
        if ($dbActive == 1) {
            $loggedIn = true;
        } else if ($dbActive == 0) {
            $loggedIn = false;
            echo "You Must Activate Your Account from Email to Login";
        }
    }
}

if ($loggedIn == false && $_POST) {
    echo "The Username or Password that you Entered is not Valid. Try Entering it Again";
}
```

In the code above, I have a problem displaying a message and I cannot seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. If the user enters in either the wrong password or username, then it displays the message

`"The Username or Password that you Entered is not Valid. Try Entering it Again"`.

This is fine, but if the `$dbActive` = 0, it should only display the message

`You Must Activate Your Account from Email to Login`.

But instead it is displaying both messages when this happens so it instead displays

`You Must Activate Your Account from Email to LoginThe Username or Password that you Entered is not Valid. Try Entering it Again`.

I know why this is happening, but I cannot seem to figure it out. How can I stop it from getting both messages to be displayed if `$dbActive` = 0?

Comment: first you need to indent your code properly

Comment: Your logic says it all - `if ($loggedIn == false && $_POST)` will evaluate to true if the form was submitted and the login failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code explains everything pretty clearly:

```
while($stmt->fetch()) {
    if ($teacherusername == $dbTeacherUsername && $teacherpassword == $dbTeacherPassword) {
        if ($dbActive == 1){
            $loggedIn = true;
        } else if ($dbActive == 0) {


            $loggedIn = false;  

/****************************
 *
 * at this point, $loggedIn == false.
 *
 ****************************/


            echo "You Must Activate Your Account from Email to Login";
        }
    }
}

/****************************
 *
 * at this point, $loggedIn == false.
 *
 * since $loggedIn == false and $_POST is truthy, your if statement will get entered.
 *
 ****************************/

if ($loggedIn == false && $_POST) {
    echo "The Username or Password that you Entered is not Valid. Try Entering it Again";
}
```

So how do we fix this? Easy! We add another variable declaring whether or not the user is active.

```
$active = true;

.
.
.

if ($dbActive == 0) {
    $loggedIn = false;
    $active = false;
    echo "You Must Activate Your Account from Email to Login";
}

.
.
.

if (!$loggedIn && $active && isset($_POST['formInputName']) {
    echo "The Username or Password that you Entered is not Valid. Try Entering it Again";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be doing this in a very odd way.

```
while($stmt->fetch()) {
```

So you're iterating through a whole list of results from the database, checking each to see if they match the user's details. Why don't you just include the details in the query itself? That way, you just need to check the return from the database - if you get a result returned, you know it's a valid login; if there's nothing, you can display your 'invalid login' message.

Once you know you've got a valid result, you can then check to see if the account needs activating.

In pseudocode:

```
if ($stmt->fetch()) {
    if ($row->$dbActive) {
        # valid login
    } else {
        # needs activation
    }
} else {
    # invalid login
}
```

Comment: I like your answer better than mine, but I figured I'd keep mine up there as a valid alternative to this beautiful code :-) +1.

Comment: @Matt - Less beautiful; more that I tend to want to find the solution that involves doing the least amount of work.

Answer (score 0):

This logic can be made simpler

From:

```
if ($dbActive == 1){
    $loggedIn = true;
} else if ($dbActive == 0) {
    $loggedIn = false;
    echo "You Must Activate Your Account from Email to Login";
}
```

to:

```
if ($dbActive == 1){
    $loggedIn = true;
} else{
    $loggedIn = false;
    echo "You Must Activate Your Account from Email to Login";
}
```

and your last condition

```
if ($loggedIn == false && isset($_POST['somefield']) {
    echo "The Username or Passwor...";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($loggedIn == false && !empty($_POST) && $dbActive != 0) {
    echo "The Username or Password that you Entered is not Valid. Try Entering it Again";
}
```